# Getting the "csrf token missing or incorrect" error in my django app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-csrf

I'm getting the "csrf token missing or incorrect" error in my django app.
I have the csrf token in my template:

```
<form action="/hello/compare_lname" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data>{% csrf_token %}
```

I use request in render() in my view.py:

```
render(request, 'delta.html',{'delta_dict': delta_dict})
```

I put a print statement in `_compare_salted_tokens` in `middleware.csrf`

```
print(request_csrf_token, csrf_token).
```

`request_csrf_token` is changing. `csrf_token` doesn't change, even if I restart the server. `csrf_token` comes from:

```
csrf_token = request.META.get('CSRF_COOKIE')
```

Do I need to reset `request.META.get('CSRF_COOKIE')` somehow?

Comment: you forgot the endquote like @bdoubleu said `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form tag is pasted directly from your template then you're missing an end quote on the `enctype` attribute.